# Construct own object from return value of MapViewOfFile()

Tags: c++, shared-memory

I want to 'cast' the return value of MapViewOfFile (as far as I know a pointer to void) to my own class, so that I am able work with this object. I know how the memory is structured. The headerSize resides at byte number 4 to byte number 8, a hex value is written in the byte for example hex 47, so the size should be 71 bytes. I want to get 71 as the value of my attribute 'headerSize'. What code has to replace 'TODO' in my snippet? I do not know how to read the bytes and how to create the attributes.

Code in main.cpp:

```
// MapViewOfFile return a pointer to void, so you need to cast it to a suitable structure 
pBuf = (FILE*) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, BUF_SIZE);
// create object
JobaShm jobaShm(pBuf);
int headerSize = jobaShm.getHeaderSize();
std::cout << " HeaderSize " << headerSize << ";\n";
```

Code in jobashm.h

```
#ifndef JOBASHM_H
#define JOBASHM
class JobaShm {
public:
    JobaShm(FILE* handle);
    int getHeaderSize();
private:
    int headerSize;
};
#endif
```

Code in jobashm.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "jobashm.h"
JobaShm::JobaShm(FILE* handle){
    // TODO 
}
int JobaShm::getHeaderSize(){
    return headerSize;
}
```

UPDATE: Due to this tutorial http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/54381/ I am trying to cast the return value of MapViewOfFile in my own struct.

main.cpp

```
struct Shm {
    int firstByte;
};
int main(void){
    std::cout << "*** Start SharedMemory  ***\n";
    HANDLE hMapFile;
    hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, szName);              
    if (hMapFile == NULL){
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Could not open file mapping object"), TEXT("ERROR"), MB_OK);
        return 1;
    }
    Shm * pBuf = (Shm *) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, BUF_SIZE); // ggf. besser size_of Shm, statt BUF_SIZE
    std::cout << " Debug  " << pBuf->firstByte << ";\n";
    UnmapViewOfFile(&pBuf);
    CloseHandle(hMapFile);
    std::cout << "*** close app by typing a number. ***\n";
    int a = 0;
    cin >> a;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to read more about MapViewOfFile.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx

It returns a pointer to the data.

```
LPCTSTR pBuf;
pBuf = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, BUF_SIZE);
JobaShm(pBuf)
```

Then since you know what the data is you should create a structure for it and cast it.

```
struct FileData {
    int space;
    int headerSize;
    // etc...
}

JobaShm::JobaShm(LPTSTR* pBuf) {
    FileData fd;
    CopyMemory((PVOID)pBuf, &fd, sizeof(fd));
    headerSize = fd.headerSize;
}
```

Comment: Great advice nykwil - do you know how I can read the byte content as well?

Comment: MapViewOfFile returns A POINTER, as nykwil said... Byte at offset 42 is read as follow: BYTE ByteAt42 = *((PBYTE)pBuf+42);

Comment: Thanks manuell, I will try your advice. Anyway my current idea is to use a struct to get the corresponding content to the returned pointer.